# Injectivity of expectation

Tags: expected-value

In a proof I read recently, I saw the author conclude that $X$ is an Exp(1) random variable after finding $E(X^{k}) = k!$.  Why and when is this allowed (i.e. when can I conclude that some r.v. follows a distribution whose expectation I recognize)? Is it not possible to construct another random variable with expectation $k!$ that *isn't* an Exp(1) random variable (maybe I just missed something earlier on)?

I haven't been able to find much online about the injectivity of the expectation function, so maybe someone can clarify for me.

Comment: The constant variable $k!$ also has that expectation.  As does the variable which is $k!\pm 1$ each with probability $\frac 12$.  You can easily find infinitely many other variables with the same expectation.

Comment: Then how can they conclude $X$ follows $\text{Exp}(1)$?

Comment: They must have more information.

Comment: In that case there is an enormous amount of information regarding the distribution.  Not least, the fact that you have the desired relation for all $k$, not just one.   But, if you have a question about that solution, you should ask the user who posted it.

Answer (score 1):

The claim is, that given $EX^k=k!$ for each $k=0,1,2,\dots$ implies $X$ has the indicated $\mathrm{Exp}(1)$ distribution.  Most of the comments to your question ignore the statement that the $\mu_k=k!$ condition  holds for all $k$, even though it is clear in the post you cite.

Read all about this kind of problem in general [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamburger_moment_problem) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carleman%27s_condition).  In your special case, since the series $$f(z)=\sum_{k\ge0} EX^k\frac {z^k}{k!}=\sum_{k\ge0}z^k = \frac 1{1-z}$$ converges for all complex $z$ in a neighborhood of $0$, there is only one probability distribution with the indicated moments.